# CakePHP 3 Customizing the Templates FormHelper Uses

Tags: cakephp-3.0, formhelper

I'd like to customize the inputSubmit template. I would like a template like that:

```
<button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
    <i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>
  </button>
```

For the moment I do that:

```
'inputSubmit' => '<button type="{{type}}" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" {{attrs}}>Submit<i class="mdi-content-send right"></i>'
```

It's working but I'd like to customize the text directly in the view template.

How can I do that ?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you really mean to say "_... directly in the Template_"? I can only assume that you didn't wanted to refer to the form helper string template that you are showing here, but to a view template where you are using the form helper? Please update your question if this is the case.

Comment: Yes exactly ! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The input function allows you to override templates on the fly:

```
$this->Form->input('name', ['templates' => ['inputContainer' => '...']]);
```

Additionally, The create function also allows to override the templates for all inputs inside that form:

```
$this->Form->create($entity, ['templates' => ['inputContainer' => '...']]);
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like to set just the content not all the tag.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I've made CustomFormHelper, which extends the FormHelper and overrides the template. As in example below.

`class CustomFormHelper extends FormHelper
{
    public function __construct(View $View, array $config = []) {
        $this->_defaultConfig['templates']['inputContainer'] = '<div class="test">{{content}}</div>';
        parent::__construct($View, $config);
    }
}`